# PyDev - Eclipse can import numpy but none of it's functions?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, numpy, pydev

I'm having a problem importing the numpy module in Eclipse. The `import numpy` line runs with no problems. But then if I try use a function from the numpy module (e.g. numpy.zeros, numpy.uint8, etc.) I get the error `Undefined variable from import`.

The functions work fine in the python interpreter or actually running a python script. The problem is Eclipse recognizing the module functions. I've had no trouble adding other such modules. All of the modules I'm using come from the [unofficial windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Once I've installed them, I've simply added the module's directory to the Eclipse interpreter libraries to get them to work. This has been unsuccessful for numpy. I've even tried adding each of the subfolders of the numpy package to the interpreter libraries. I've checked the import in the interpreter using a verbose run of Python to see what all happens during the import, but I don't see much that I haven't already tried added to the Eclipse interpreter libraries. I attempted using earlier versions of numpy and the version from the official numpy site as well, but with the same result. I tried adding the numpy directory to the project PYTHONPATH specifically as well, but with no success there either.

I'm using Windows 7, Python 2.7, and 64-bit versions of all the packages (and python).

Any suggestions? Thank you much!

Comment: To be clear, you are seeing this as an error message from PyDev's static code analysis system, not as a runtime exception that actually stops your program from executing when run from within PyDev, correct?

Comment: @SilasRay: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that since [`numpy.__init__`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py) conditionally loads itself on `import` with the `if __NUMPY_SETUP__` block, the static analyzer has no idea which branch will run, and thus just fails to identify what would end up in the module's namespace whatsoever.  You should try adding NumPy to the [forced builtins](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins) in PyDev.  I've had similar problems with other libraries (for instance, anything off `flask.ext`), but basically have just learned to ignore them.

Comment: I've attempted adding `numpy` directly to the forced builtin, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. Is there anything special I need to do when adding it as a forced builtin to get it to work?

Comment: Like I said, I've just learned to ignore them for the most part, so I don't have much experience massaging things like this.  All I can say is that poking around the net says you need to have numpy on the system path (not just project and/or python path) and that you need to wait a bit sometimes for the forced builtins you add to kick in, as PyDev has to fire up a shell and prod the modules to extract the required info from them.

Comment: I guess until another solution comes up I'll just do something similar with `import numpy.__init__ as numpy #@UnresolvedImport`. That way I've still got everything and there are no errors on the screen.